# Create Query in before hook in feathers js for nested object

Tags: nested, hook, rethinkdb, feathersjs

how can i create a query in before hook that will match nested object and return desired result ? I have objects like following in rethinkdb and I want to use something like `hook.params.query = {paymentAccounting : {Contact : {Name : 'XYZ'}}}` in the before find hook . It seems working for a straight forward object but what about nested object?How to match  paymentAccounting >Contact > Name ?

```
{
"id": "5f45451a-653a-4dc7-b135-25dec3aa25b5",
"paymentAccounting": {
    "Account": {
        "value": "4"
    },
    "Amount": 50,
    "Contact": {
        "ContactID": "68",
        "Name": "XYZ"
    },
    "Invoice": {
        "Date": "2018-01-05",
        "InvoiceID": "230"
    },
    "PaymentID": "237"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`feathers-rethinkdb` does not support querying nested fields at the moment but it is possible to [customize the query](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-rethinkdb) and add your custom query parameters in a hook:

```
app.service('mesages').hooks({
  before: {
    find(context) {
      const query = this.createQuery(context.params.query);

      const searchString = "my search string";

      hook.params.rethinkdb = query.filter(doc => {
        return doc('paymentAccounting')('Contact')('name').eq('XYZ')
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: it gives me an error `this.createQuery` is not a function @daff